# How can I get vim to show document path in Terminal?

Tags: vim, escape-characters, terminal.app

OS X 10.11 adds a nice feature to Terminal.app that interprets control sequences of the form

```
ESC ] 6 ; file://hostname/<path-as-URL> BEL
```

as specifying the "document" which is currently being edited or viewed. As an example, entering

```
echo -e "\x1b]6;file://localhost/etc/passwd\a"
```

will cause the terminal title to display the filename `passwd`, which can be cmd+clicked on to get a breadcrumb trail (a feature of the "document title" in most file editors on OS X). The OS X default `bashrc` already uses this sequence to insert the current working directory into the window title.

I'd like to know how I can get Vim to output this particular escape sequence whenever it edits a new file (and, ideally, how to unset it once the editing stops - e.g. on quit or file change). Extensions to e.g. `less` and other programs would also be very helpful.

Although the URL technically has to be properly URL-encoded, I'm totally fine if it isn't - I don't usually edit files with particularly unusual filenames in Vim.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind giving up the usual `title` handling in Vim, you can hijack that. It emits to the terminal, and can be adjusted to issue the appropriate sequences:

```
set t_ts=^[]6;file://localhost
set t_fs=^G^M
set title
autocmd BufEnter * let &titlestring = expand("%:p")
```

Use <kbd>control+v</kbd> and then <kbd>esc</kbd> to get the literal characters for the control characters shown above. A function around `vim` in your shell will wipe out the setting (the `VimLeave` `autocmd` I could not get to work in 7.3, and there's also the if-you-suspend `vim` problem).

```
function vim {
    command vim "$@"
    echo -ne "\033]6;\007"
}
```

`:help title` for details on `title`, or have a look in the Vim `src/term.c` file for the code.